# looping through an array with a Switch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

basically I have a list of url's showing different things. One url has a lot of sub parts.
Instead of making a lot of different switch statements. I was wondering If could use an array. So when i click on the btn I have a dropdown with the url end /explore/this always changes.

```
 var exploreAddedLink = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f"];

  switch (locationUrl) {
          case '/channels':
              $scope.contentLink = "Edit this Channel";
              $scope.one = "tags";
              $scope.two = "channel";
            break;
          case '/explore/'+exploreAddedLink+'':
              $scope.contentLink = "Title";
              $scope.one = "tags";
              $scope.two = "";
            break;
            case '/all-videos':
                $scope.contentLink = "Edit this Video";
                $scope.one = "videos";
                $scope.two = "";
              break;
          default:

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing batter way will be create some map and callback function like:

```
var exploreAddedLink = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f"];

var urls = {
  '/channels': function($scope){
    $scope.contentLink = "Edit this Channel";
    $scope.one = "tags";
    $scope.two = "channel";
},
  '/all-videos': function($scope){
    $scope.contentLink = "Edit this Video";
    $scope.one = "videos";
    $scope.two = "";
}};

angular.forEach(exploreAddedLink, function(extraLinkPart){
  urls['/explore/'+extraLinkPart] = exploreAction;
});

function exploreAction ($scope){
  $scope.contentLink = "Title";
  $scope.one = "tags";
  $scope.two = "";
}

/*use*/

urls[locationUrl]($scope);
```

**Edit**

You can function to get correct action:

```
function getUrlAction(url){
   if(url){
     return urls[url];
   }

   return function(){};
}

/*use*/
getUrlAction(locationUrl)($scope);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, what if the page loads a url thats not listed? will       {{contentLink}} not apear?

Comment: @ronoc4 look at added part ;)